# How do I color points separately when plotting multiple line graphs with a common x-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make 3 stacked line graphs, L, F & P, all with a common x axis depth, and the points colored by Depo. I have found multiple ways of stacking the graphs but I am struggling to integrate my desired color coding for the points.

Here is some example data - sorry it won't stay formatted as a table for some reason

```
depth     L     F     P Depo
67.48 1.003 1.063 1.066 Turb
67.63 1.004 1.020 1.024 Dri
67.73 1.011 1.017 1.028 Dri
67.83 1.006 1.007 1.014 Turb
67.92 1.003 1.029 1.032 Pro
68.06 1.004 1.007 1.011 Pro
```

I can sort of get what I want by making the graphs and then using grid.draw to stack them. But this repeats the x axis values for each graph.

```
Lin <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=L)) + geom_line() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=L, color = Depo))    
Fab <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=P)) + geom_path() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=P, color = Depo))    
Fol <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=F)) + geom_path() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=F, color = Depo))    

grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(Fol), ggplotGrob(Lin), ggplotGrob(Fab), size = "last"))
```

The following works to plot the graphs without the x axis being repeated but I can't figure out how to change the points by Depo.

```
mm <- melt(subset(MyData, select=c(depth, L, F,P)), id.var="depth")

ggplot(mm, aes(x = depth, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(color = variable)) +
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = "free_y") + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest not using `melt`. In my experience, it's hard to use correctly and mistakes are made easily. I personally prefer the `tidyr` verbs `gather()` and `spread()`.

Here's my approach to your graph:

```
MyData %>%
  gather(variable, value, L:P) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(depth, value) +
  geom_path() + geom_point(aes(color = Depo, shape = Depo), size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y")
```

The first step is a `gather` operation on the L, F and P columns, keeping depth and Depo. My code for the graph is not very different from what you'd already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the x-axis for the upper plots:

```
Lin <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=L)) + geom_line() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=L, color = Depo)) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                                                            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                                                            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())   
Fab <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=P)) + geom_path() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=P, color = Depo)) 
Fol <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=depth, y=F)) + geom_path() + geom_point(data = MyData, aes(x=depth, y=F, color = Depo)) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                                                              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                                                                                                                              axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(Fol), ggplotGrob(Lin), ggplotGrob(Fab), size = "last"))
```